# Partial derivative with respect to y of logarithm?

Tags: partial-derivative

I don't understand how to do partial derivatives of log.

My question is how to do $\frac{\partial}{\partial y} (\log_y(9x))$. Do I treat $9x$ as a constant? I know the general derivative of a log is $\frac 1{x\ln(b)}$. Please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$9x$ would be a constant. What you can do is let $f(x,y)=\log_y(9x)$. Then using change of base, $f(x,y)=\frac{\ln(9x)}{\ln(y)}$. Then $f_y=\frac{\ln(y)0-\ln(9x)\frac{1}{y}}{\ln^2(y)}=\frac{-\ln(9x)}{y\ln^2(y)}$

Edit: I interpreted the post to mean log base $y$, others might have interpreted differently.

Comment: Why did you derivate $\ln (9x)$ ,shouldn't it be constant?

Comment: I used quotient rule even though it wasn't necessary. It gives the same answer though.

Comment: ohh u did quotient rule!

Comment: @Naomi did you mean base $y$?

Comment: yes @avid19 i meant base y.

Comment: how do i do it with respect to x. so i did the change of base lke you did and  im using the quotient rule like $\frac{0-(1/9)(9)ln(y)}{ln^2(y)}$? @avid19

Answer (score 0):

Yes, $9x$ is a cosntant considered as a function in the variable $y$.